# Push notifications with JavaPNS successful but nothing on mobile device

Tags: iphone, jakarta-ee, tomcat, apple-push-notifications, javapns

**Problem:** My code appears to be executing fine, no errors, and proper log results, or so it appears, but no push notifications end up on the iPhone. I'm sending the notifications from Apache Tomcat running on a Mac: Mountain Lion.

**Note:** I can get this to run using the same certificates, except in .pem format in php. Javapns will not accept .pem so I use .p12 files. Since the .pem version of my certificates works in php I'm starting to suspect this entire problem is a shortcoming of javapns.

**Background:**
The code below executes without error and the `notifications.isSuccessful()` is actually returning true. But I am receiving no message on my device and no error. When I had previously utilized the wrong key I got appropriate errors, and when my token string was too long I had received errors. Now the application finally runs with no exception but nothing is reaching the device.

```
    String keyFilePath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("")+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"keys"+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"key.p12";                    
List<PushedNotification> notifications = Push.combined (pushNotificationMessage, 1, "Sound.wav", keyFilePath, "Password", false, userToken);   
for (PushedNotification notification : notifications) {
        if (notification.isSuccessful()) {                                     
                System.out.println("Push notification sent successfully to: " +
                                                notification.getDevice().getToken());

        } else {
                String invalidToken = notification.getDevice().getToken();  
                Exception theProblem = notification.getException();
                theProblem.printStackTrace();

                /* If the problem was an error-response packet returned by Apple, get it */  
                ResponsePacket theErrorResponse = notification.getResponse();
                if (theErrorResponse != null) {
                        System.out.println(theErrorResponse.getMessage());
                }
        }
}
```

**LOGS**

```
2014-05-16 20:29:21 DEBUG Payload:219 - Adding alert [blah blah blah]
2014-05-16 20:29:21 DEBUG Payload:193 - Adding badge [1]
2014-05-16 20:29:21 DEBUG Payload:205 - Adding sound [Sound.wav]
2014-05-16 20:29:21 DEBUG ConnectionToAppleServer:94 - Creating SSLSocketFactory
2014-05-16 20:29:21 DEBUG ConnectionToAppleServer:149 - Creating SSLSocket to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
2014-05-16 20:29:22 DEBUG PushNotificationManager:111 - Initialized Connection to Host: [gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com] Port: [2195]: 5dec07cc[SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL: Socket[addr=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com/17.172.232.45,port=2195,localport=51223]]
2014-05-16 20:29:22 DEBUG PushNotificationManager:538 - Building Raw message from deviceToken and payload
2014-05-16 20:29:22 DEBUG PushNotificationManager:617 - Built raw message ID 1 of total length 154
2014-05-16 20:29:22 DEBUG PushNotificationManager:396 - Attempting to send notification: {"aps":{"sound":"Sound.wav","alert":"blah blah blah","badge":1}}
2014-05-16 20:29:22 DEBUG PushNotificationManager:397 -   to device: cb45519c4516907a03b3b5c2f0e48aa51f6f3d900cb7598f4e3c4482b33afea8
2014-05-16 20:29:22 DEBUG PushNotificationManager:415 - Flushing
2014-05-16 20:29:22 DEBUG PushNotificationManager:417 - At this point, the entire 154-bytes message has been streamed out successfully through the SSL connection
2014-05-16 20:29:22 DEBUG PushNotificationManager:420 - Notification sent on first attempt
2014-05-16 20:29:22 DEBUG PushNotificationManager:222 - Reading responses
2014-05-16 20:29:27 DEBUG PushNotificationManager:200 - Closing connection
Push notification sent successfully to: cb45519c4516907a03b3b5c2f0e48aa51f6f3d900cb7598f4e3c4482b33afea
```

**Registration**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
    if (notificationTypes != (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound) ) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound) ];
        NSLog(@"Reregistering for notifications");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Notifications Found");
    }

return YES
}
```

**Obtaining the Token**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString *stringToken = [[[[deviceToken description]
                               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                              stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                             stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
    //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
    [self sendPNToken:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",stringToken]];
    NSLog(@"StringToken: %@",stringToken);
}
```

**System**

Mountain Lion/Mac, Apache Tomcat, JDK 1.7

Comment: Can you show your application code where you register for APNS?

Comment: Sure but I'm not getting issues there.

Comment: @Eran just added my registration and token extraction code.